# One of the columns has empty values ​and they are joined to another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

There are empty values ​​in the [date] column, they are connected to the [name_ru] column and Power BI produces incorrect results

`Table.AddColumn(#"Changed column type", "name_full", each [name_ru] & ", " & [date])`

[image]

How to avoid joining with an empty value in the [date] column

Comment: Can you clarify the question. It isn't currently clear

Comment: I would like to have only rows in the output in the PBI filter [name_ru] + [date]
no gaps. It is possible to add some condition or function.
If there is an empty value, do not print the line